# Creating a Docker Compose for Rail App with Cassandra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, cassandra

I am trying to create a docker compose file for my below set up:

Rubyonrail app on the host.

DB is a 3-node cassandra which resides in three distinct containers.

Could you help creating a docker compose file for this particular setup ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to you to build a cassandra cluster based `docker-compose`

https://github.com/jdgoldie/cassandra-docker-compose/blob/master/docker-compose.yml.

You can declare your node by

```
#
# Datacenter 1 non-seed node
#
nodedc1: 
    image: rajcy/cassandra_compose
    environment:
        - DATACENTER=DC1
```

You can read it  [Here](https://github.com/jdgoldie/cassandra-docker-compose)

and for docker file for the Docker(3) you can consider [this](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/f61f8951219708e3d17819a0833db2927bc76330/3.1/Dockerfile)

Comment: Thanks. Let me clarify my question. I need the Dockers composer file for the rubyobrail app which works with Cassandra node. I am struggling to define the Cassandra part of the environment within the docker compose file of the app I have set up.

Thanks again for the help.